# Get the last day of next three weeks Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to get the last day of next three weeks.

For example,if today is Wednesday,16 April ,I will get the result Sunday,4 May.

I have written a function like this

```
public static Date nexThreeWeekEnd() {
    Date now = new Date();
    Date nextWeeks = DateUtils.truncate(DateUtils.addWeeks(now, 3), Calendar.DATE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(nextWeeks);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

DateUtils is used from this library:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
```

But this function will return Wednesday, 7 May, that's mean it will return exactly the day of current date.

It's not necessary to rewrite my function. Any other ways to solve my problem will be very appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In the example you gave you specify two to three weeks, should it return three weeks from a sunday or two weeks?

Comment: Question is contradictory. Your first sentence says three weeks out, but your second sentence’s example of 2014-05-04 is only two weeks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code hope it helps

```
   Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
   int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
   int leftDays= Calendar.SUNDAY - currentDay;
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, leftDays)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2);

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

Output:

```
2014/05/04
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek();
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 4);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

IN Java we can make use of Gregorian calendar

please check if below code helps you

```
    Date d = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar cal1  =  new GregorianCalendar();
    cal1.setTime(d);
    System.out.println(cal1.getTime());
    int day = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
    cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-(day-1));/*go to start of the week*/
    cal1.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,3); // add 3 weeks 
    day = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );// get the end Day of the 3rd week
    System.out.println("end of the 3rd week  ="+day);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Question and other Answers use old outmoded classes.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` & `.Calendar`. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and time zone. You can use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to generate a new `LocalDate` value relative to the original. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note the plural) class implements several handy such adjusters includning the one we need, [`nextOrSame( WeekOfDay )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-). The [`WeekOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) class is a handy enum representing each of the seven days of the week, Monday-Sunday.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of ( 2014 , Month.APRIL , 16 );
LocalDate nextOrSameSunday = start.with ( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) );
LocalDate twoWeeksAfterNextOrSameSunday = nextOrSameSunday.plusWeeks ( 2 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start: " + start + " | nextOrSameSunday: " + nextOrSameSunday + " | twoWeeksAfterNextOrSameSunday: " + twoWeeksAfterNextOrSameSunday );
```

> start: 2014-04-16 | nextOrSameSunday: 2014-04-20 | twoWeeksAfterNextOrSameSunday: 2014-05-04